# How do I click on "Next" button until it disappears in playwright (typescript)

Tags: typescript, while-loop, playwright

Here is the code I am using to click next button until it disappears on pagination.

Then, I can verify the record on the last page

The issue is, when it is in the last page, still tries to find the locator, and gives error because of the timeout.

But, I need to exit from the loop when it is disappeared

```
while (true) {
      try {
        await page.locator("//div[@class='next-button']").click();
        await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
      } catch (error) {
        break;
      }
    }
```

Comment: use `.count()` instead of click

Comment: The code shown here should work, although if the button isn't rendered asynchronously, you might want to use `$` to grab it without waiting, or `.count()` to determine if it exists, as suggested above. Sure, the timeout error is triggered on the last page, but you catch it and break out of the loop.

Comment: What are you achieving as a test validation by let's say clicking 'Next' 20 times ? It doesn't sound like a useful test to me as per the provided info.

Comment: I need to verify an order id in the last page of the pagination. But, I don't know how many pages are there. So, I want to go to the last page. If there is only one page, no need to click "Next" button. If there are 19 pages, it should click on it 18 times @VishalAggarwal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses `page.waitForSelector` to wait for the selector to be present and visible. If the selector is not found within the specified timeout (2 seconds in this case), it returns `null`. The code then checks if `nextButton` is truthy, meaning the element is present and visible. If so, it clicks on it, waits for a timeout, and continues the loop. If `nextButton` is falsy (null), the loop breaks.

Here's how it works:

1. `page.waitForSelector` returns a promise that resolves to the element handle when the selector is found and meets the specified conditions (in this case, being visible). If the selector is not found within the specified timeout, it rejects the promise.
2. The `.catch(() => null)` part catches any rejected promise (error) and provides a fallback value of `null`. In other words, if the selector is not found within the specified timeout, the promise is rejected, and the `catch` block ensures that the `nextButton` variable is set to `null`.

So, if `page.waitForSelector` successfully finds the element and resolves the promise, `nextButton` will contain the element handle. If there's an error (e.g., the element is not found within the timeout), `nextButton` will be `null`.

```
while (true) {

  const nextButton = await this.page.waitForSelector("//div[@class='next-button']", { state: 'visible', timeout: 2000 }).catch(() => null);
    
  if (nextButton) {
    await nextButton.click();
    await this.page.waitForTimeout(1000);
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This what I would do in general:

```
while(somethingNotTrueOnlyOnLastPage) 
{

// Test validation
}
```